# Add vertical padding to tabular with a bmatrix in it

Tags: tables, matrices

I am creating the following table:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \text{sign of} c & f & i & \text{Resulting Matrix}\\
        \hline
        $\geq 0$ & $\geq 0$ & $\geq 0$ & 
        $
        \begin{bmatrix}
            -2c^2+1 & -2cf & 2ci\\
            -2cf & -2f^2+1 & 2fi\\
            -2ci & -2fi & 2i^2-1
        \end{bmatrix}$\\
        \hline
        $\geq 0$ & $\geq 0$ & $\leq 0$ & $ 
        \begin{bmatrix}
            -2c^2+1 & -2cf & -2ci\\
            -2cf & -2f^2+1 & -2fi\\
            2ci & 2fi & 2i^2-1
        \end{bmatrix}$
        \\
        \hline
        $\geq 0$ & $\leq 0$ & $\geq 0$ &
        $\begin{bmatrix}
            -2c^2+1 & 2cf & 2ci\\
            2cf & -2f^2+1 & -2fi\\
            -2ci & 2fi & 2i^2-1
        \end{bmatrix}$\\
        \hline
        $\geq 0$ & $\leq 0$ & $\leq 0$ & $
        \begin{bmatrix}
            -2c^2+1 & 2cf & -2ci\\
            2cf & -2f^2+1 & 2fi\\
            2ci & -2fi & 2i^2-1
        \end{bmatrix}$
        \\
        \hline
        $\leq 0$ & $\geq 0$ & $\geq 0$ & 
        $\begin{bmatrix}
            -2c^2+1 & 2cf & -2ci\\
            2cf & -2f^2+1 & 2fi\\
            2ci & -2fi & 2i^2-1
        \end{bmatrix}$\\
        \hline
        $\leq 0$ & $\geq 0$ & $\leq 0$ & 
        $\begin{bmatrix}
            -2c^2+1 & 2cf & 2ci\\
            2cf & -2f^2+1 & -2fi\\
            -2ci & 2fi & 2i^2-1
        \end{bmatrix}$
        \\
        \hline
        $\leq 0$ & $\leq 0$ & $\geq 0$ & 
        $\begin{bmatrix}
            -2c^2+1 & -2cf & -2ci\\
            -2cf & -2f^2+1 & -2fi\\
            2ci & 2fi & 2i^2-1
        \end{bmatrix}$
        \\
        \hline
        $\leq 0$ & $\leq 0$ & $\leq 0$ & 
        $\begin{bmatrix}
            -2c^2+1 & -2cf & 2ci\\
            -2cf & -2f^2+1 & 2fi\\
            -2ci & -2fi & 2i^2-1
        \end{bmatrix}$
        \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{All the matrcies which yield from casework on $c,f,i = \pm \sqrt{c^2}, \pm \sqrt{f^2}, \pm \sqrt{i^2}$.}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
```

It ends up looking like this:
[image: Matricies are Cramped together on the right, compiled with Overleaf]

As you can see, there is no vertical space between the top of the cell and the top of the matrix that is in it. Is there any way to fix that? Adding `\vspace` doesn't help as it creates blanks in the vertical bars. I also tried `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{<factor>}`, but that simply stretches the matrices without adding any vertical padding within the cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the TeX.SE. You can use `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}` into the code near to `tabular`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    {\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \text{sign of} c & f & i & \text{Resulting Matrix}\\
        \hline
        $\geq 0$ & $\geq 0$ & $\geq 0$ & 
        $
        \begin{bmatrix}
            -2c^2+1 & -2cf & 2ci\\
            -2cf & -2f^2+1 & 2fi\\
            -2ci & -2fi & 2i^2-1
        \end{bmatrix}$\\
        \hline
        $\geq 0$ & $\geq 0$ & $\leq 0$ & $
        \begin{bmatrix}
            -2c^2+1 & -2cf & -2ci\\
            -2cf & -2f^2+1 & -2fi\\
            2ci & 2fi & 2i^2-1
        \end{bmatrix}$
        \\
        \hline
        $\geq 0$ & $\leq 0$ & $\geq 0$ &
        $\begin{bmatrix}
            -2c^2+1 & 2cf & 2ci\\
            2cf & -2f^2+1 & -2fi\\
            -2ci & 2fi & 2i^2-1
        \end{bmatrix}$\\
        \hline
        $\geq 0$ & $\leq 0$ & $\leq 0$ & $
        \begin{bmatrix}
            -2c^2+1 & 2cf & -2ci\\
            2cf & -2f^2+1 & 2fi\\
            2ci & -2fi & 2i^2-1
        \end{bmatrix}$
        \\
        \hline
        $\leq 0$ & $\geq 0$ & $\geq 0$ & 
        $\begin{bmatrix}
            -2c^2+1 & 2cf & -2ci\\
            2cf & -2f^2+1 & 2fi\\
            2ci & -2fi & 2i^2-1
        \end{bmatrix}$\\
        \hline
        $\leq 0$ & $\geq 0$ & $\leq 0$ & 
        $\begin{bmatrix}
            -2c^2+1 & 2cf & 2ci\\
            2cf & -2f^2+1 & -2fi\\
            -2ci & 2fi & 2i^2-1
        \end{bmatrix}$
        \\
        \hline
        $\leq 0$ & $\leq 0$ & $\geq 0$ & 
        $\begin{bmatrix}
            -2c^2+1 & -2cf & -2ci\\
            -2cf & -2f^2+1 & -2fi\\
            2ci & 2fi & 2i^2-1
        \end{bmatrix}$
        \\
        \hline
        $\leq 0$ & $\leq 0$ & $\leq 0$ & 
        $\begin{bmatrix}
            -2c^2+1 & -2cf & 2ci\\
            -2cf & -2f^2+1 & 2fi\\
            -2ci & -2fi & 2i^2-1
        \end{bmatrix}$
        \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}}
    \caption{All the matrcies which yield from casework on $c,f,i = \pm \sqrt{c^2}, \pm \sqrt{f^2}, \pm \sqrt{i^2}$.}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The tool of choice for vertical padding in tabular is `cellspace`, which defines a minimal padding in cells of columns with specifier  prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C` if you load `siunitx`, which defines an S column type).

I also propose a different layout, with only horizontal rules from `booktabs`, and the use of the `measuredfigure` environment from `threeparttable`. Also, a a code simplification with the use of `array` in the place of `tabular`, and a fine suggestion  from @BarbaraBeeton for ‘normalising‘ the square roots  in the caption:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{4pt}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
 \centering
    \begin{measuredfigure}%[h!]

    $ \begin{array}{ccc!{\quad}Sc}
        \toprule
        \text{sign of } c & f & i & \text{Resulting Matrix}\\
        \midrule
 \geq 0 & \geq 0 & \geq 0 &
 $ \begin{bmatrix}
 -2c^2+1 & -2cf & 2ci \\
 -2cf & -2f^2+1 & 2fi \\
 -2ci & -2fi & 2i^2-1
 \end{bmatrix} $\\
 \cmidrule(r){1-3}
   \geq 0 & \geq 0 & \leq 0 &
 $ \begin{bmatrix}
 -2c^2+1 & -2cf & -2ci\\
 -2cf & -2f^2+1 & -2fi\\
 2ci & 2fi & 2i^2-1
 \end{bmatrix} $ \\
 \cmidrule(r){1-3}
 \geq 0 & \leq 0 & \geq 0 &
 $ \begin{bmatrix}
 -2c^2+1 & 2cf & 2ci\\
 2cf & -2f^2+1 & -2fi\\
 -2ci & 2fi & 2i^2-1
 \end{bmatrix} $ \\
 \cmidrule(r){1-3}
 \geq 0 & \leq 0 & \leq 0 &
 $ \begin{bmatrix}
 -2c^2+1 & 2cf & -2ci\\
 2cf & -2f^2+1 & 2fi\\
 2ci & -2fi & 2i^2-1
 \end{bmatrix} $ \\
 \cmidrule(r){1-3}
 \leq 0 & \geq 0 & \geq 0 &
$ \begin{bmatrix}
 -2c^2+1 & 2cf & -2ci\\
 2cf & -2f^2+1 & 2fi\\
 2ci & -2fi & 2i^2-1
 \end{bmatrix} $ \\
 \cmidrule(r){1-3}
 \leq 0 & \geq 0 & \leq 0 &
$ \begin{bmatrix}
 -2c^2+1 & 2cf & 2ci\\
 2cf & -2f^2+1 & -2fi\\
 -2ci & 2fi & 2i^2-1
 \end{bmatrix} $ \\
 \cmidrule(r){1-3}
 \leq 0 & \leq 0 & \geq 0 &
 $ \begin{bmatrix}
 -2c^2+1 & -2cf & -2ci\\
 -2cf & -2f^2+1 & -2fi\\
 2ci & 2fi & 2i^2-1
 \end{bmatrix} $ \\
 \cmidrule(r){1-3}
 \leq 0 & \leq 0 & \leq 0 &
$ \begin{bmatrix}
 -2c^2+1 & -2cf & 2ci\\
 -2cf & -2f^2+1 & 2fi\\
 -2ci & -2fi & 2i^2-1
 \end{bmatrix} $\\
 \bottomrule
    \end{array} $
  \caption{All the matrices which yield from casework on $c,f,i = \pm \sqrt{c^2}, \pm \sqrt{\smash[b]{f^2}}, \pm \sqrt{i^2}$.}
 \label{fig:my_label}
\end{measuredfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very kind Bernard improved the whole MWE: there is a part out of {}

Comment: Thank you for warning me, @Sebastiano!

Comment: Looks nice.  Now, it might be nice to "normalize" the radicals in the caption.  Either smashing the bottom of the `f` or adding `\mathstrut` to the other two would do it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Excellent suggestion! What do you think, semantically, of ‘compressing’ the three square roots, under a single symbol (I mean something like \sqrt{c^2, \smash[b]{f^2}, i^2})?

Comment: I'm not sure enough mathematically that compressing them is equivalent.  I'm inclined to be conservative and leave them separate.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Done, milady!